# in SQL Server 2008 how can I get the list of stored procedures which are inserting data in a given table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add a field in a table. This field will need to be populated with different values.

I already know the main stored procedures which insert new records in this table and those stored procedures will need to be modified. To stay on the safe side is there a way I can get the full list of stored procedures which insert records in the table in question?

sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities gives me the list of stored procedures which are dependant on this table but I only want the stored procedures which insert records not the ones which simply query it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to look on the code of the stored procedure itself, but it probably won't be a 100 percent match. Something on the lines of:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(S.object_id) StoredProcedure
FROM sys.sql_modules S
JOIN sys.procedures P
ON S.object_id = P.object_id
WHERE Definition LIKE '%INSERT INTO myTable%' 
OR Definition LIKE '%INSERT myTable%'
```

Comment: Nice answer but incomplete. This doesn't work when schema prefixes are used, doesn't search for whole words and moreover ignores square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know that we have a way to get a hard match based on DML statement (insert vs delete), but you might try comparing the referencing entities dataset against a string match like so:

```
declare @ObjectName nvarchar(517) = 'dbo.Person';

declare @match table (sName nvarchar(500), oName nvarchar(500))
insert into @Match (sName, oName)
    select distinct
            object_schema_name([object_id], db_id()),
            object_name([object_id], db_id())
    from    sys.sql_modules
    where   [definition] like '%'+@ObjectName+'%' and
            (   -- match "insert into dbo.Person" or "insert into Person"
                [definition] like '%insert into ' + @ObjectName + '%' or
                [definition] like '%insert into ' + replace(@ObjectName, 'dbo.', '') + '%' or
                -- match "insert dbo.Person" or "insert Person"
                [definition] like '%insert ' + @ObjectName + '%' or
                [definition] like '%insert ' + replace(@ObjectName, 'dbo.', '') + '%' 
            )

select  *   
from    sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(@ObjectName, 'OBJECT') re
left
join    @Match d on
        re.referencing_schema_name = d.sName and
        re.referencing_entity_name = d.oName
where   d.sName is not null -- comment this line to compare all possible ref entities 
return
```

Answer (score 0):

One low-tech tactic that works better than you might think . . .

Dump the schema to text. Then at a command prompt . . .

```
$ grep -i 'insert into your-table-name' dumped-schema-file
```

I don't know the Windows utility that searches for a text string.

That will probably find most of the inserts. You might also try

```
$ grep -i -B2 'your-table-name' dumped-schema-file
```

That will print every line that matches 'your-table-name', along with the three lines immediately before it, so you can look for things like

```
insert into
your-table-name
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Magazine published an article titled [Stored Procedure Searches for Strings](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/stored-procedure-searches-for-strings.aspx) a few years ago that provided a stored procedure that

> accepts an input string and searches
>   the syscomments, sysobjects, and
>   syscolumns system tables in the local
>   database for any reference to that the
>   string. The output result set shows
>   all the tables, procedures, views, and
>   other elements that contain the
>   specified input string.

It's basically a grep for your database. It's been very useful.